# How can my searchbar go full width and hide other elements

Tags: html, css, searchbar

I have nav menu you can look at the snippet. (its not responsive in this case). And my problem is that i want to make searchbar (on hover with page max-width980px) to hide all elements and to be full width in nav menu. Problem is that i have very poor understanding of javascript so if is there any css only solution. I tried adding z-index but without effect.

```css
/* Navigation menu */


.resmenu {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.resmenuitems {
        display: none;
}
.navmenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(240,240,240);
}

.logo {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    
}


.navlinksr {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 490px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-around;
}

.navlinksr a {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
    
}




.navlinksline {
    height: 40%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.logodif {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.rlynothing {
    margin-left: 4%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.rlynothingagain {
    height: 40%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
}



/* SEARCH */

.swrap{
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 30px;
}


.search-container { 
    float:left;
  display: flex;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: width .2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.search-container:hover{
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
}


.search-input {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.search-input input {
  flex: 1;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.navlinkborder {
    background-color: limegreen;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.navlinkborder:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="sk">
    
<head>

    <!-- Site info -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js"></script>
    

</head>
    
<body>

    <!-- BEGIN - Header -->
    <div class="navmenu">
    <a href="index.php">   
    <div class="logo">
    <p>Coding</p>&nbsp;<p class="logodif">Hub</p>
    </div>
    </a> 
        
    <div class="rlynothing">
        <div class="rlynothingagain">
        </div>
    </div>
        
     <div class="swrap">
 <div class="search-container">
  <div class="search-icon-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="search-input">
    <input type="search" class="search-bar" placeholder="Hľadať...">
  </div>
</div>
         </div> 

    
   <div class="resmenu" id="flip">
      <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>  
    </div>
          
    <div class="navlinksr">
        <a href="archiv.php">Archív</a>
        <a href="#">Live</a>
        <a href="donate.php" class="navlinkborder" style="color: white">PODPORIŤ</a>
        <a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a> 
        <a class="navlinksline"></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Prihlásiť sa</a>
    </div>
        
  
        
          
    </div>
   
    <div id="panel" class="resmenuitems">
    <a href="archiv.php">Archív</a>
    <a href="donate.php">PODPORIŤ</a>
    <a href="archiv.php">Live</a>
    <a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Prihlásiť sa</a>
    </div>
    <!-- END - HEADER -->
```

Comment: Can't the header logo be fixed size instead of flex?

Comment: A lot of things are different then it should be. I am beginner.

Comment: I see. I'll try and set the fix header logo and see how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below
set the header as fixed

```
.logo {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.rlynothing {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

set search container full width

```
.search-container { 
    float:left;
    display: flex;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.search-container:hover{    
    background: white;
    width: calc(100% - 264px); /* 264px is the width of Header Image */
    border-color: black;
}
```

You can calculate the width search bar using calc().
And to show the search bar above other elements, use position: absolute(relative) and z-index.
For z-index to work, you need to use position : absolute or position : relative

```css
/* Navigation menu */


.resmenu {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.resmenuitems {
        display: none;
}
.navmenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(240,240,240);
}

.logo {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    
}


.navlinksr {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 490px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-around;
}

.navlinksr a {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
    
}




.navlinksline {
    height: 40%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.logodif {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.rlynothing {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.rlynothingagain {
    height: 40%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
}



/* SEARCH */

.swrap{
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 30px;
}


.search-container { 
    float:left;
    display: flex;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.search-container:hover{
    background: white;
    width: calc(100% - 264px); /* 264px is the width of Header Image */
    border-color: black;
}


.search-input {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.search-input input {
  flex: 1;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.navlinkborder {
    background-color: limegreen;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.navlinkborder:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="sk">
    
<head>

    <!-- Site info -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js"></script>
    

</head>
    
<body>

    <!-- BEGIN - Header -->
    <div class="navmenu">
    <a href="index.php">   
    <div class="logo">
    <p>Coding</p>&nbsp;<p class="logodif">Hub</p>
    </div>
    </a> 
        
    <div class="rlynothing">
        <div class="rlynothingagain">
        </div>
    </div>
        
     <div class="swrap">
 <div class="search-container">
  <div class="search-icon-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="search-input">
    <input type="search" class="search-bar" placeholder="Hľadať...">
  </div>
</div>
         </div> 

    
   <div class="resmenu" id="flip">
      <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>  
    </div>
          
    <div class="navlinksr">
        <a href="archiv.php">Archív</a>
        <a href="#">Live</a>
        <a href="donate.php" class="navlinkborder" style="color: white">PODPORIŤ</a>
        <a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a> 
        <a class="navlinksline"></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Prihlásiť sa</a>
    </div>
        
  
        
          
    </div>
   
    <div id="panel" class="resmenuitems">
    <a href="archiv.php">Archív</a>
    <a href="donate.php">PODPORIŤ</a>
    <a href="archiv.php">Live</a>
    <a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Prihlásiť sa</a>
    </div>
    <!-- END - HEADER -->
```